# radiobutton in different tabs stay checked

Tags: c#, radio-button

I have a winforms app witch has a `tabcontrol` and in each tab some `radiobuttons` the code works but there is a problem.
If i go to a tab and check a `radiobutton` and after go to another tab and check another `radiobutton` the previous button stays selected.
Is there a way to whenever i check a radiobutton on another tab the app unchecks the previous button on the other tab?
The code i use is:

```
            if (!radioButton1.Checked && !radioButton2.Checked && !radioButton3.Checked && !radioButton4.Checked)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select an option!", "Warning");
                return;
            }
            else if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                build build = new build("@../Images/x1.jpg", "definition", "c1");
                build.ShowDialog();
 }  
            else if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                build build = new build("@../Images/x2.jpg", "definition2","c2");
                build.ShowDialog();
            }
```

etc...

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you just want to uncheck all other radiobuttons? You could just use to uncheck them:

```
radioButtonX.Checked = False;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the events for the tabControl. Make an event for the tabPageX.Enter and clear the radio button (radioButtonX.Checked = false) in that.

Really, unless this is a throw-away test software, I'd recommend looking into a more sophisticated architecture like Model View Presenter. (for what its worth).

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for the help. i added:         
`private void tabControl1_TabIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            radioButton9.Checked = false;
        }`
But still not working, ami missing something?
Sorry but as you can figure out i´m a noob in c#

Comment: No worries. I think I understand your problem better now that I think about it. For each tabIndex, you can use (in your example) tabPage1_Leave (which gets called when you switch to a different tab) to uncheck the radiobutton. This way you don't have the button checked when you switch to it, because you uncheck it before you leave it. Does that make sense?